# How to add notranslate for currency symbols - woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, symbols, currency

Does anyone know how to stop Google translate from translating just the currency symbol?

I have installed GTranslate to translate woocommerce site. It translates well - however it also translates the currency symbol from £ to Euro. I have serched and found many of the same answer to prevent the currency symbol from being translated.

It involves wrapping every £ sign with a span like, £ this is impractical, takes too long and may need to be removed at a later date.

I thought I would try via a filter in the functions file as mentioned on the woocommerce website (see below) However, it doesn't work - possibly Google is translating it after the filter?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'change_existing_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function change_existing_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
     switch( $currency ) {
          case 'AUD': $currency_symbol = 'AUD$'; break;
     }
     return $currency_symbol;
}
```

Any help or suggestions woul dbe appreicated, I'm a bit stumped on this one.

Thnaks in advance

Comment: The `class="notranslate"` and the the HTML5 [translate="no"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-translate-attribute) attribute  will do the trick

Comment: Hi @mujuonly thanks for your reply. However adding a clas to the span would be impractical for every insatnce of the symbol. Ideally, would like to add it to the functions file somehow

Comment: I've eadded a new js file with the following script and enqueued it. But it's not working :-/ `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol").addClass('notranslate');
});`